# sql server cluster - "the given network name is unusable" error in creation wizard

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a sql server 2008 R2 cluster.

I've got two windows machines running server 2008 that are clustered and have all passed the validation tests etc.

I'm now going through the "Install a sql server failover cluster" wizard and am on the "Instance Configuration" page.

This is a brand new machine with nothing but windows and .net3.5 installed.
I've given it a sql server network name, named the instance differently, the instance ID is the same as the instance name.

Hit next and I get the following error

> [Error Message]
>   
> The given network name is unusable because there was a failure trying to determine if the network name is valid for use by the clustered SQL instance due to the following error: 'The network address is invalid.'
>   
>   [Details]
>   
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingValidationException: The given network name is unusable because there was a failure trying to determine if the network name is valid for use by the Clustered SQL instance due to the following error: 'The network address is invalid.'

Has anyone seen this before and found a solution? I've tried google and came up with sites saying it was a bug with the installer and to tweak the registry which sounded dodgy.

If you need any more information I'll provide anything you ask for, I wasn't sure what would be useful.

Thank you

Comment: I've found the fix.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk-UA/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/d96afca2-9cb7-4a5c-b8a9-9ee2d3fedef1

uninstall VMware tools, install SQL Server 2008 in clustered mode, then reinstall vmware tools. Something in VMware tools seems to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the fix.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk-UA/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/d96afca2-9cb7-4a5c-b8a9-9ee2d3fedef1

> Here is a workaround for this issue that appears under the following conditions;
>   VMware ESX 4 Update 1
>   SQL Server 2008 slipstreamed with SP1
>   Windows Server 2008 R2

You will need to use E1000 network adapters (as the drivers are included in windows), uninstall VMware tools, install SQL Server 2008 in clustered mode, then reinstall vmware tools. Something in VMware tools seems to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

And likewise if you are using VirtualBox uninstalling the Virtual Box Additions (tools) allows you to continue.